# Luigi show percentage of completed tasks in the command line

Tags: luigi

In workflow management systems when you have a vast number of tasks, you often need to see the number (or the percentage) of tasks that are completed.

Other wfms systems such as Snakemake do it by default. Though, I could not find a similar functionality in Luigi's documentation.

I would like to see the percentage information on the command line.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Luigi team have done this, because their approach is to run a central scheduler daemon to scale. They would probably accept a pull request that hooks into their central scheduler daemon to get the total number of tasks currently in the queue and those completed. One issue, though, is that you can use the central scheduler for many different workflows at once, so semantically, it may be harder to figure out which tasks you are counting. Finally, if you are running a sufficiently large number of jobs (10,000s in my experience), I would not use Luigi, due to it's overhead. You can see my experience with it here: [AWS Step Functions vs Luigi for orchestration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715338/aws-step-functions-vs-luigi-for-orchestration/62200442#62200442)

If are not tied to the command line however, just use the web interface they provide. It is quite informative.